# Encriptação em ASCII em C

Tags: c

Preciso de ajuda com isso, eu ja fiz as funções que encriptão e desencriptão, ele encripta normal, porem, na hora da desencriptação ele com certeza não faz o processo corretamente.

O erro e o seguinte: para encriptar eu acho que ele encripta corretamente eu ate fiz um pritf ali pra ver o resultado e como ele ta controlando os arrays, porem na hora de desencriptar ele come uma letra da senha, e diz que tem um caractere á mais no arquivo, alem do indice da senha ir de 1 à 8 sendo que eu acho que deveria ir de 0 à 7 como na encriptação.

**segue um "Log" doque acontece:**

```
    ESSE E O LOG DELE ENCRIPTANDO
    O---------------------------------------O
    |     WELCOME TO ENCRYPTION SYSTEM      |
    |---------------------------------------|
    | 1 - Encrypt file                      |
    | 2 - Decrypt file                      |
    | 0 - Quit                              |
    O---------------------------------------O
    o--> 1
    Please, enter password: Senha123
    Enter the name of the source file: test.txt
    The source file will be encrypted in the target file.
    Enter the target file name: enc
    File chars: 15
    Password chars: 8
    char: �[15] - encrypted: � - password: S[0]
    char:  [14] - encrypted: � - password: e[1]
    char: z[13]  - encrypted:  - password: n[2]
    char: t[12] - encrypted: # - password: h[3]
    char: n[11] - encrypted: 0 - password: a[4]
    char: e[10] - encrypted: i - password: 1[5]
    char: W[9]  - encrypted: v - password: 2[6]
    char:  [8]  - encrypted: � - password: 3[7]
    char: s[7]  - encrypted: 9 - password: S[0]
    char: o[6]  - encrypted: + - password: e[1]
    char: i[5]  - encrypted: ( - password: n[2]
    char: c[4]  - encrypted: 4 - password: h[3]
    char: i[3]  - encrypted: 5 - password: a[4]
    char: n[2]  - encrypted: ` - password: 1[5]
    char: i[1]  - encrypted: d - password: 2[6]
    char: V[0]  - encrypted: v - password: 3[7]



    ESSE E O LOG DELE DESECRIPTANDO
    O---------------------------------------O
    |     WELCOME TO ENCRYPTION SYSTEM      |
    |---------------------------------------|
    | 1 - Encrypt file                      |
    | 2 - Decrypt file                      |
    | 0 - Quit                              |
    O---------------------------------------O
    o--> 2
    Please, enter password: Senha123
    Enter the name of the source file: enc
    The encrypted file will be dencrypted in the target file.
    Enter the target file name: dec
    File chars: 16
    Password chars: 8
    char: �[16] - decrypted:  - password: [8]
    char: �[15] - decrypted: � - password: 3[7]
    char: �[14] - decrypted: � - password: 2[6]
    char: �[13] - decrypted: � - password: 1[5]
    char: �[12] - decrypted: � - password: a[4]
    char: �[11] - decrypted: � - password: h[3]
    char: �[10] - decrypted: � - password: n[2]
    char: �[9] - decrypted: � - password: e[1]
    char: �[8] - decrypted:  - password: [8]
    char: �[7] - decrypted: � - password: 3[7]
    char: �[6] - decrypted: � - password: 2[6]
    char: �[5] - decrypted: � - password: 1[5]
    char: �[4] - decrypted: � - password: a[4]
    char: �[3] - decrypted: � - password: h[3]
    char: �[2] - decrypted: � - password: n[2]
    char: �[1] - decrypted: � - password: e[1]
    char: �[0] - decrypted:  - password: [8]
```

segue a explicação:

**Algoritmo 1 – Algoritmo de encriptação de texto**
Deve ser desenvolvido um programa para encriptar e decriptar arquivos de texto. O programa deve solicitar ao usuário o nome do arquivo com o texto a ser encriptado, o nome do arquivo de destino do texto encriptado, e uma palavra-chave para a encriptação. Com essas informações o programa deve criar o segundo arquivo contendo o texto encriptado. Este mesmo programa deve fazer a decriptação do arquivo de texto. O programa deve solicitar ao usuário o nome dos arquivos de origem (texto encriptado) e destino (texto puro) e a palavra-chave que foi utilizada na encriptação, o programa deve gerar o arquivo de destino contendo o texto puro (decriptado).

**Protocolo de encriptação:** Dado uma palavra-chave qualquer (e de qualquer tamanho), o programa deve ler do arquivo de texto blocos de texto (vetor) do tamanho dessa palavra-chave, o vetor deve ser invertido
e calculado um deslocamento em cima de cada elemento do bloco de texto, a quantidade a ser deslocada deve ser o número ASCII do elemento correspondente na palavra-chave, deve ser utilizado apenas os caracteres imprimíveis da tabelas ASCII, que vão de -127 +127 (ou 0-255).

**Exemplo:**
Texto exemplo: Este e um texto exemplo qualquer!
Palavra-chave: “Senha123”

tamanho da palavra-chave: 8, logo serão lidos blocos de dados de 8 em 8. ex: “Este e u”, o bloco deve ser invertido, ex: “u e etsE”, e calculado o deslocamento da palavra-chave, no caso: 83, 101, 110, 104, 97, 49, 50, 51.

A partir dessa informação deve-se aplicar o deslocamento em cima de cada elemento do bloco de texto, por exemplo, o bloco de texto (já invertido) “u e etsE” possui os seguintes códigos ASCII: 117, 32, 101, 32, 101 ,116, 115, 69. Agora basta somar o deslocamento com os códigos do bloco de texto, exemplo: 83+117, 101+32, 110+101, 104+32, 97+101, 49+116, 50+115, 51+69. Isso é igual à: -55, -122, -44, -119, -57, -90, -90, 120. Logo o texto encriptado deve ficar parecido com este: “ɆԉǦ\A6x]”. Observe que eu disse parecido, e não idêntico, pois como os caracteres apresentado não são padrões, a exibição gráfica deles deve variar de sistema operacional para sistema operacional.

Essa operação deve ser desfeita através da função de decriptar no mesmo programa, que basicamente fará
o processo inverso.

**Segue os codigos das funções que fazem a encriptação e a desencriptação:**

**ENCRIPTA**

```
    #include "encryptEngine.h"
    void encrypt(FILE* sourceFile, FILE* encryptedFile, char* password) {
      char* sourceFileName = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_FILE_LENGTH);
      char* encryptedFileName;

      setPassword(password);
      setFileName(sourceFileName);
      if((sourceFile = fopen(sourceFileName, "r")) != NULL) {
        encryptedFileName = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_FILE_LENGTH);
        setEncryptedFileName(encryptedFileName);
      } else {
        fileErrorHandler("notExist");
      }

      int index, indexPass;
      char auxiliary, encryptedChar;

      rewind(sourceFile);
      fseek(sourceFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
      printf("File chars: %d\n", ftell(sourceFile));
      printf("Password chars: %d\n", sizeof(password));
      if((encryptedFile = fopen(encryptedFileName, "w")) != NULL) {
        indexPass = 0;
        index = ftell(sourceFile);
        while(index >= 0L){
          fseek(sourceFile, index, SEEK_SET);
          auxiliary = fgetc(sourceFile);
          encryptedChar = 255 - (password[indexPass] + auxiliary);
          printf("char: %c[%d] - encrypted: %c - password: %c[%d]\n", auxiliary, index, encryptedChar, password[indexPass], indexPass);
          fprintf(encryptedFile, "%c", encryptedChar);
          indexPass++;
          if(indexPass == sizeof(password)) {
            indexPass = 0;
          }
          index--;
        }
        printf("\n");
      } else {
        fileErrorHandler("fileName");
      }
      fclose(sourceFile);
      fclose(encryptedFile);
      free(sourceFileName);
      free(encryptedFileName);
    }
```

**DESENCRIPTA**

```
    #include "decryptEngine_new.h"
    void decrypt(FILE* encryptedFile, FILE* decryptedFile, char* password) {
      char* encryptedFileName = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_FILE_LENGTH);
      char* decryptedFileName;

      setPassword(password);
      setFileName(encryptedFileName);
      if((encryptedFile = fopen(encryptedFileName, "r")) != NULL) {
        decryptedFileName = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_FILE_LENGTH);
        setDecryptedFileName(decryptedFileName);
      } else {
        fileErrorHandler("notExist");
      }

      int index, indexPass;
      char auxiliary, decryptedChar;

      rewind(encryptedFile);
      fseek(encryptedFile, 0L, SEEK_END);
      printf("File chars: %d\n", ftell(encryptedFile));
      printf("Password chars: %d\n", sizeof(password));
      if((decryptedFile = fopen(decryptedFileName, "w")) != NULL) {
        indexPass = sizeof(password);
        index = ftell(encryptedFile);
        while(index >= 0L) {
          fseek(encryptedFile, index, SEEK_END);
          auxiliary = fgetc(encryptedFile);
          decryptedChar = (255 - auxiliary) - password[indexPass];
          printf("char: %c[%d] - decrypted: %c - password: %c[%d]\n", auxiliary, index, decryptedChar, password[indexPass], indexPass);
          fprintf(decryptedFile, "%c", decryptedChar);
          indexPass--;
          if(indexPass == 0) {
            indexPass = sizeof(password);
          }
          index--;
        }
        printf("\n");
      } else {
        fileErrorHandler("fileName");
      }
      fclose(encryptedFile);
      fclose(decryptedFile);
      free(encryptedFileName);
      free(decryptedFileName);
    }
```

Ficaria muito feliz com uma ajuda, ou ate mesmo uma dica, não quero a resposta para o problema pois gosto de fazer por min mesmo, porem, estou a 3 dias com o problema.

Comment: Próxima vez tente criar uma versão reduzida do seu problema ao invés de postar o arquivo inteiro. Com um programa menor é muito mais fácil de debugar. Sem contar que tirando todos os detalhes de leitura de arquivo, etc, fica bem mais fácil de outras pessoas reproduzirem seu bug e que também não sei se seu professor vai achar legal que você está postando o código do dever de casa na internet de onde seus colegas podem copiar :)

Comment: Relaxa amigo, vai não, isso e so uma parte do codigo, e errado por sinal :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Antes de mais nada, veja [a observação de hugomg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55746/215) a respeito da forma de calcular o tamanho da senha. Deveria ser `strlen(password)` e não `sizeof(password)`.

Seu problema está na forma como você está tratando os limites dos intervalos (no caso da senha com certeza, e muito provavelmente no caso do arquivo também). Quando você encripta:

```
indexPass++;
if(indexPass == sizeof(password)) {
    indexPass = 0;
}
```

Você garante que `indexPass` jamais seja igual a `sizeof(password)` [quando ele for usado], no máximo 1 a menos que ele. E como ele começa (e recomeça) do zero, então o intervalo sendo usado de fato é:

```
[0, sizeof(password)[
```

Já quando você decripta:

```
indexPass--;
if(indexPass == 0) {
    indexPass = sizeof(password);
}
```

Você garante que ele jamais seja igual a zero, no máximo 1 a mais, e você começa e recomeça de `sizeof(password)`:

```
]0, sizeof(password)]
```

A consequência você já deve imaginar: o primeiro caractere da senha nunca é usado, e o terminador nulo (`\0`) no final da senha às vezes é usado (que no caso de uma cifra de Vigenère significa que o caractere ficará inalterado).

De todo modo, isso é irrelevante, pois pelo modo como você está implementando o algoritmo não é necessário percorrer a senha "de trás pra frente" - se o primeiro caractere da mensagem foi combinado com o primeiro caractere da chave, o primeiro caractere da cifra deve ser combinado *também* com o primeiro caractere da chave... De modo que na sua função de decifragem você deve usar o mesmo loop para percorrer a senha que você usou no processo de cifragem.

(e se você fosse mesmo percorrer tudo de trás pra frente, ainda restaria o problema do *padding* - a menos que o tamanho do arquivo fosse múltiplo do tamanho da senha, apenas *parte* dela seria usada perto do final do arquivo. Complicando ainda mais sua implementação...)

Quanto ao problema do arquivo, eu não tenho experiência suficiente com o C para dizer com certeza, mas *muito provavelmente* é da mesma natureza: o `fseek(encryptedFile, index, SEEK_END)` coloca a posição - no meu entender - não no seu último byte, mas 1 além dele (de novo, pela convenção dos intervalos fechados no início e abertos no final). Além disso, uma olhada rápida nos seus códigos mostrou um uso inconsistente de `SEEK_END` e `SEEK_SET` (não sei se é proposital, como falei tenho pouca experiência prática com C).

Encripta:

```
  while(index >= 0L){
      fseek(sourceFile, index, SEEK_SET);
```

Desencripta:

```
  while(index >= 0L) {
      fseek(encryptedFile, index, SEEK_END);
```

Sugiro dar uma conferida nisso.

Comment: Obrigado pelo resposta meu amigo, ela me ajudou muito, e eu percebi outra coisa que eu estava fazendo errado, no enunciado fala que e para eu inverter um bloco do tamnaho da senha e encripar, e assim por diante, eu estou reimplementando aqui, muito obrigado e um grande abraço

Answer (score 2):

Um erro que você tem no seu código é que `sizeof(password)` não contém o número de letras da senha. Ele vai ser o tamanho do ponteiro, que provavelmente vai ser sempre 4.

Em C você deve sempre passar o tamanho dos seus vetores como um parâmetro separado.

Comment: Nossa, nem percebi esse detalhe! Em todo caso, quando se usa strings terminadas por nulo [como entrada] não vejo muita necessidade de usar um parâmetro separado - `strlen` deve bastar. (o mais engraçado é que por coincidência o AP usou uma senha de 8 letras numa arquitetura de 64 bits... :P)

Comment: Você está certo mas em geral é melhor testar se o caracter atual é nulo ao invés de usar strlen. Um erro muito comum é botar um strlen dentro dum loop pra ver se "chegou no final", o que acaba sendo muito ruim para performance (strlen precisa varrer a string inteira toda vez que você chame)

Comment: Olha obrigado pela resposta, eu li que daria para usar o sizeof no password, porque ele é um ponteiro, não sei se esta certo.

Comment: É justamento o contrário do que te falaram. Dá pra usar o sizeof em um array que você referencia diretamente mas assim que você converte esse array para um ponteiro ou passa o array para alguma outra função você perde a informação do tamanho do array original.